# Removing empty page between list of acronyms and nomenclature in frontmatter of twoside page book

Tags: double-sided, xindy, glossaries-extra, nomencl

I am trying to get rid of extra empty page in `\frontmatter` of `\documentclass[twoside]{book}` between passages of Abbreviations and List of symbols. I am using for printing and managing list of symbols package nomenclature.

MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true }
% arara: nomencl
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara:  lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }
% arara:  lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside] {book}              
\usepackage [czech] {babel} 
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}            
\usepackage [left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm] {geometry}      
\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}   

%List of Abbreviations
\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, automake, abbreviations,%
                    stylemods=longbooktabs%
                    ]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Acronym}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Description}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\usepackage{ifthen}
  \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{P}}{Physics Constants}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{Other Symbols}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{N}}{Number Sets}{}}}%
  ]}

% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Symbol definitions}

%Abbreviations
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{beginning of alphabet}
\newacronym{def}{DEF}{another part of alphabet}

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\frontmatter                                        
\pagestyle{plain}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist, nopostdot, title=Abbreviations] 

%Symbols
\nomenclature[P]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial system
    \nomunit{$299,792,458\, m/s$}}

\nomenclature[N]{$\mathbb{R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[O]{$V$}{Constant Volume}

\printnomenclature

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

On final note: I have only beginner knowledge of LaTeX, solution to this might be easy, but I can't find it. Also, if you compile MWE, you get 2 blank pages on the beginning. I don't know why, in original document, that I am working with, those don't appear, so no need to resolve that issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards, Tomáš

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty pages are inserted because the list of abbreviations and the list of symbols are each treated like a chapter, which are only supposed to start on left hand pages. To avoid this problem, one can temporally change the definition of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true }
% arara: nomencl
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara:  lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }
% arara:  lualatex: { synctex: true, shell: true }

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside] {book}              
\usepackage [czech] {babel} 
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}            
\usepackage [left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm] {geometry}      
\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}   

%List of Abbreviations
\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, automake, abbreviations,%
                    stylemods=longbooktabs%
                    ]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Acronym}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Description}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\usepackage{ifthen}
  \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{P}}{Physics Constants}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{Other Symbols}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{N}}{Number Sets}{}}}%
  ]}

% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Symbol definitions}

%Abbreviations
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{beginning of alphabet}
\newacronym{def}{DEF}{another part of alphabet}

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\frontmatter                                        
\pagestyle{plain}

{
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist, nopostdot, title=Abbreviations] 

%Symbols
\nomenclature[P]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial system
    \nomunit{$299,792,458\, m/s$}}

\nomenclature[N]{$\mathbb{R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[O]{$V$}{Constant Volume}

\printnomenclature
}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly :)
Since it is temporarily, the changed state of \cleardoublepage ends after "}" after \printnomenclature?

Comment: @TomášKruliš Exactly, the redefinition only affects the things inside `{...}`, everything else will be left untouched